# I can`t save a table to a csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape a table from Wikipedia with scrappy, the problem is I can`t save it as csv file.
This is my code

```
import scrapy 

class DCspider( scrapy.Spider ):
    name = 'ufcspider'
    def start_requests(self):
        url_short = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Fighting_Championship_rankings"
        yield scrapy.Request(url = url_short,
                         callback = self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
        # Create an extracted list of the table 
        table = response.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"wikitable")]/text()').extract()
        filepath = "ufc.csv"
        with open(filepath, "w") as f:
            f.writelines([parragraphs + "\n" 
            for parragraphs in table])
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: "Code not working" isn't a working problem description. Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can write to a csv file with `csv` library. Following code may help you:

```
import scrapy 
import csv

class DCspider( scrapy.Spider ):
    name = 'ufcspider'
    def start_requests(self):
        url_short = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Fighting_Championship_rankings"
        yield scrapy.Request(url = url_short,
                     callback = self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
        # Create an extracted list of the table 
        table = response.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"wikitable")]/text()').extract()
        filepath = "ufc.csv"
        with open(filepath, "w") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
            for parragraph in table:
                writer.writerow([parragraph + "\n"])
```